# Update a column with the result-dataset-count of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `#data` which has the columns `Id` and `Count`. In addition I have a stored procedure `MyProc` which accepts a parameter `@id` (*equals the `Id` column*) and returns a dataset (*the count equals the `Count` column*).

My goal is to assign the `Count` column from `Id` with `MyProc` without a cursor.

I know, something like this does not work:

```
UPDATE d
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (EXEC MyProc d.Id))
FROM #data AS d
```

Is there a syntax I do not know or is a cursor the only option to achieve this?

PS: It is a code quality and performance problem for me. Calling the stored procedure would be the easiest way without repeating 50 lines of SQL but a cursor slows it down.

Comment: A cursor is the only way in this case. If you want to improve performance you need to crack open the stored procedure and try to rewrite it in a set based fashion then you can do it for a whole bunch of ID's. You could also rewrite your SP as a scalar valued function. Then you could do it without a cursor but you would still have a performance issue. If you post your SP code we might be able to help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can make use of the below query :

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE data;
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyFunct') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunct;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE data 
    (
      ID      int,
      [Count] int
    );

    INSERT data VALUES (1,5), (1,10), (2,3), (4,6);
    GO

    UPDATE d
    SET d.[Count] = f.CNT
    FROM 
        (SELECT ID,COUNT(id) AS CNT FROM data GROUP BY ID) f 
    INNER JOIN data d ON f.ID = d.ID
```

I couldn't find a way to use Stored procedure. Needed you can use Table valued function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunct(@id INT)
    RETURNS @i TABLE
    (ID INT , CNT INT)
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @i 
        SELECT ID,COUNT(id) AS CNT FROM data GROUP BY ID
    RETURN 
    END;
    GO

    UPDATE d
    SET d.[Count] = f.CNT
    FROM dbo.MyFunct(1) f INNER JOIN data d ON f.ID = d.ID
```

Comment: Using a helper *table valued function* which returns the table was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To do what you say, you need a function, not a procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFunc (@Id INT)
    RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE someTable
     SET someCol = 'someValue'
   WHERE id = @Id;  

  RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;
END
GO
```

Then call the function in your update statement;

```
UPDATE d
   SET d.Count = dbo.myFunc(d.Id)
  FROM #data AS d;
```

However, row-based operations is bad practice. You should always strive to perform set-based operations, but as I don't know what your procedure does, I cannot provide more than a wild guess to what you should do (not using a procedure at all):

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Id INT);

UPDATE x
   SET x.someCol = 'SomeVal'
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @data
  FROM someTable AS x
 INNER JOIN #data AS d
         ON d.Id = x.Id;

WITH cte (Id, myCount) AS (
    SELECT d.Id
          ,COUNT(d.Id) AS myCount
      FROM @data AS d
     GROUP BY d.Id
)
UPDATE d
   SET d.[Count] = c.myCount
  FROM #data AS d
 INNER JOIN cte AS c
         ON c.Id = d.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do but I think your solution will involve @@ROWCOUNT; Observe:

```
-- Sample data and proc...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #data;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyProc') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.MyProc;
GO

CREATE TABLE #data 
(
  id      int,
  [Count] int
);

INSERT #data VALUES (1,5), (1,10), (2,3), (4,6);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc(@id int)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 'some value'
  FROM #data
  WHERE @id = id;
END;
GO
```

**Data BEFORE:**

```
id          Count
----------- -----------
1           5
1           10
2           3
4           6
```

**A routine that uses @@ROWCOUNT**

```
DECLARE @someid int = 1; -- the value you're passing to your proc

EXEC dbo.MyProc 1;
DECLARE @rows int = @@ROWCOUNT; -- this is what you need.

UPDATE #data
SET [Count] = @rows
WHERE id = @someid;
```

**Data AFTER**

```
id          Count
----------- -----------
1           2
1           2
2           3
4           6
```

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is an interesting idea but not what I need. The core problem is, that I have to update all rows. This means I have to call my SP pretty often and a cursor would slow it down. I would like to avoid the cursor, but so far it looks like it is not possible